# Run a simple text file as Java

Tags: java, text, compiler-construction

I have a simple .txt file which has pure Java code inside it like

```
   public class C {
      public static void main(String[] args ) {
        System.out.println("This is executed");
        }
    }
```

The file is named C.txt. Now I want to write Java code that will read the code in C.txt and will compile and run the read code as a pure Java file. Note, I can easily rename C.txt to C.java and compile and run the code manually. However, this is not my intention. I want to read the .txt file as is and execute the code directly. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: does writing a shell script work for you?  it'd be a good bit easier than trying to implement this in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'd start with [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/home.html), which allows you to compile and execute Java source held in a string.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [javax.tools](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html) api form Java 6 to compile the code on the fly. However since your extension is illegal it will complain with a **error: C.txt Class names are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested**.

To get around this (as mentioned in the comments) you must first load the code into a String and then execute it:

```
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.SimpleJavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class MyCompiler2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String program = "";
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C.txt"));
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                program += str;
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> fileObjects;
        fileObjects = getJavaSourceFromString(program);

        compiler.getTask(null, null, null, null, null, fileObjects).call();

        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("C");
        Method m = clazz.getMethod("main", new Class[]{String[].class});
        Object[] _args = new Object[]{new String[0]};
        m.invoke(null, _args);
    }

    static Iterable<JavaSourceFromString> getJavaSourceFromString(String code) {
        final JavaSourceFromString jsfs;
        jsfs = new JavaSourceFromString("code", code);
        return new Iterable<JavaSourceFromString>() {
            public Iterator<JavaSourceFromString> iterator() {
                return new Iterator<JavaSourceFromString>() {
                    boolean isNext = true;

                    public boolean hasNext() {
                        return isNext;
                    }

                    public JavaSourceFromString next() {
                        if (!isNext)
                            throw new NoSuchElementException();
                        isNext = false;
                        return jsfs;
                    }

                    public void remove() {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }
}

class JavaSourceFromString extends SimpleJavaFileObject {
    final String code;

    JavaSourceFromString(String name, String code) {
        super(URI.create("string:///" + name.replace('.', '/') + Kind.SOURCE.extension), Kind.SOURCE);
        this.code = code;
    }

    public CharSequence getCharContent(boolean ignoreEncodingErrors) {
        return code;
    }
}
```

Notice how you need to explicitly provide the **method** and **class** name in order for reflection to execute your code.

Comment: The `JavaCompiler` *can* compile source in a `String`.  There is an example in the JavaDocs using `JavaSourceFromString`.  I use it in [STBC](http://pscode.org/stbc).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this thread for how to start the compile from within Java...

[How to set the source for compilation by a CompilationTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873576/how-to-set-the-source-for-compilation-by-a-compilationtask/5873662#5873662)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I understood that we can compile and files. But I would also like to execute the compiled .class files . How to do it ?